Aggregate xts coredata in case of duplicate indices
Assuming I have the following xts object with duplicated time information:
library(xts)

x <- xts(1:5, 
         c("2024-04-19", "2024-04-19", "2024-04-20", "2024-04-21", "2024-04-21") |> as.Date())
x
#>            [,1]
#> 2024-04-19    1
#> 2024-04-19    2
#> 2024-04-20    3
#> 2024-04-21    4
#> 2024-04-21    5

Currently I'm simply discarding duplicate entries to "clean" the object in a rather naive way for further use/analysis:
ind <- zoo::index(x) |> duplicated()
x[!ind, ]
#>            [,1]
#> 2024-04-19    1
#> 2024-04-20    3
#> 2024-04-21    4

I would like to expand this towards a more sophisticated approach (at least from my point of view) where I would be able to choose some common aggregation function to be applied on duplicated indices, returning an object of class xts, e.g.
xts_aggr_duplicates(x, "mean")
#>            [,1]
#> 2024-04-19    1.5
#> 2024-04-20    3
#> 2024-04-21    4.5

xts_aggr_duplicates(x, "sum")
#>            [,1]
#> 2024-04-19    3
#> 2024-04-20    3
#> 2024-04-21    9

My idea was to disassemble the complete object, aggregate where necessary and rbind again... But this would be pretty inefficient for large objects, I guess. Any ideas?

Use aggregate.zoo. In the code below replace mean with whatever function you prefer.
library(xts)
aggregate(x, c, mean) |> as.xts()
##            [,1]
## 2024-04-19  1.5
## 2024-04-20  3.0
## 2024-04-21  4.5

If the way you got x in the first place is reading it in from a file
then use read.zoo.
write.zoo(x, "myfile.dat") # create test file

read.zoo("myfile.dat", aggregate = mean) |> as.xts()
##            [,1]
## 2024-04-19  1.5
## 2024-04-20  3.0
## 2024-04-21  4.5

Note
Input in reproducible form.
library(xts)
x <- xts(1:5, 
  as.Date(c("2024-04-19", "2024-04-19", "2024-04-20", "2024-04-21", "2024-04-21")))


I was hoping for a one-liner but did not expect one... :) Could you please explain briefly why aggregate(by = c) only considers duplicate index values? I don't really get why this works but it's pretty cool it does! Also thanks for the note, edited my question accordingly.

It applies the function specified in the second argument to the time index and then aggregates on equal values much like tapply.  See ?aggregate.zoo
